# MYSQL LIKE IN / Matching Substring

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following two statements and want to get this in only one statement. Is that possible?

Statement One, getting Content from the last 2 Days:

```
SELECT  
    c.ID SUBTAG
FROM 
    `content` c, 
    posts p   
WHERE 
    c.id = p.id_content AND
    from_unixtime(p.scheduled) BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,now()) AND  from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
ORDER BY from_unixtime(p.scheduled)
```

With c.id i need to get sum(qty) from Orders. Like that:

```
 SELECT 
    sum(Qty) Bestellungen, 
    SUBTAG  
 FROM 
    Orders 
 WHERE SubTag Like '%c.id%'
 GROUP BY SubTag
```

Within the table orders the Column Subtag doesnt exactly has the c.id. Its just part of the Column. That's why i need the like! Subtag in Table Orders looks like 132_**subtag**_kjsdf4382.

Table Orders looks like:

```
Date_           Price   Qty     SubTag  
2017-02-20      14.98   1       b1a8cc_2_qgsGairwtape
2017-02-20      14.98   1       b1a8cc_3_qgdfgdirwtape
```

posts look like:

```
ID      id_content      scheduled           ad_active   posted 
3015    82              1487754540          0            1
```

And content looks like:

```
ascsubid    ID              
b1a8cc      82
```

Result from the query should look like:

```
SubTag   Orders
b1a8cc      2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: good idea. i've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT 
    sum(Qty) Bestellungen, 
    SUBTAG  
 FROM 
    Orders 
 WHERE SubTag in 
    (SELECT c.ID 
     FROM `content` c, posts p   
     WHERE c.id = p.id_content AND
     from_unixtime(p.scheduled) BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,now()) AND 
     from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
     and c.id Like '%c.id%')
 GROUP BY SubTag;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for below statement.

```
 SELECT 
    sum(Qty) Bestellungen, 
    SUBTAG  
 FROM 
    Orders 
 WHERE SubTag Like '%' + c.id + '%';
 GROUP BY SubTag
```

Comment: `want to get this in only one statement` I don't think this is an answer to the question, you are still using two different SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Qty) Bestellungen, 
    SubTag  
 FROM 
    Orders 
 WHERE EXIST
    (SELECT c.ID 
     FROM `content` c, posts p   
     WHERE c.id = p.id_content 
           AND from_unixtime(p.scheduled) BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,now()) AND from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
           AND Orders.SubTag LIKE CONCAT('%', c.ID, '%') )
 GROUP BY SubTag;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Orders.Qty) Bestellungen, 
    Orders.SubTag 
FROM
    (SELECT  
        c.ID SUBTAG
    FROM 
        `content` c, 
        posts p   
    WHERE 
        c.id = p.id_content AND
        from_unixtime(p.scheduled) BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,-2,now()) AND  from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))
    ORDER BY from_unixtime(p.scheduled)
    ) Tag INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.SubTag LIKE CONCAT('%', Tag.SubTag, '%') 
GROUP BY 
    Orders.SubTag
```